# OKTA issue while application is logging in

Tags: java, endpoint, okta, http-status-code-400, okta-api

I am using [Authorization grant type-authorization code](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcode/main/) in my java application (not sping boot).

I have the below issue.

1. In browser enter okta server url
2. okta authenticates
3. now it enters into okta console and shows all the applications that user have proper access to
4. I clicked on my application → it takes me to my application properly.
5. I just clicked X to close the tab.
6. Then again I clicked on application, its not returning access token and id token. It throws 400 error when i call /token endpoint.
7. Then I clicked on X to close the tab.
8. I did the same step 6 & 7, it worked good…
9. Again step 6 & 7, it throws me 400 error.

I am seeing the below message.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://XXX.oktapreview.com/oauth2/<auth_id>/v1/token
```

Summary, it works good alternatively. I am not sure what is happening.

When I check log in okta server, there is no scope defined when it throws 400 error. It passes scopes correctly alternatively. Is this something to do with this issue?
image

Comment: Does it work fine, if you start your flow from your application rather? Configuring Okta to support "IdP" initiated flow for OIDC might be bit tricky. But I'd definitely recommend you to log all the calls you make to Okta, so that you can restore the flow. So far it's not clear from your explanation what it is

Comment: When I hit my application URL, each time it always takes me to OKTA login page and my application opens correctly on entering credential and authenticated by okta.

Can you tell me what do you mean by restore the flow?

Comment: I'd suggest then to stick to the flow which is working. Or are you expecting your users to log into Okta first to click the chicklet to log into your app? By default, OIDC application do not support the latter flow in Okta. I'm sorry, I haven't understood your question `Can you tell me what do you mean by restore the flow?`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Philipp.

Found the issue. Looks like okta code is becoming invalid when tab is closed and when i try to use the old okta code it threw me 400 error. Changed my code flow to get new okta code whenever the application is triggered from okta dashboard. That solved the problem.